# Why does it fail to assign values to variable in Grid?

Tags: grid-layouts, assignment

I have a grid such as the following, and want to assign the values in the second row to the variable in the first row, but it always fail, can you provide a solution? Thank you!

```
constant = 
 Grid[{{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}}, Frame -> All]
constant[[1, 1]] // FullForm
constant[[1, 2]] // FullForm
constant[[1, 1]] = constant[[1, 2]]
a
b
c
```

The results are:

[image]

They are not what I want `a=1, b=2...`  Why?

But if I use `{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`, it  will succeed.

Comment: `Grid` is a display wrapper, don't use it to define things as it interferes with everything. Just for display.

Comment: You are modifying `constant` if you  want to set `a` etc then try `Evaluate[constant[[1, 1]]] = constant[[1, 2]]` but it will only work when `a` and friends don\t have values/

Comment: @Roman, Because I have a lot of constant values used in a program, and the program can be used repeatedly only the constant are different, so I want to find a intuitive way to change the constant, the Grid not only can display the values while expressing their one-to-one correspondence, but also give a easy way to modify their values later. Thank you for your attention!

Comment: @Kuba, Your method basically solved my problem, only the `constant` was damaged which will not display `a,b,c,d....` but their values `1,2,3...`.  However, in general, this is an acceptable answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Roman, you shouldn't use display wrappers (such as `Grid`, `MatrixForm`, etc) in definitions of anything that you want to use in subsequent calculations.

Aside from that, here are two options:

One is to store the names of the variables as strings.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
vars = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};
values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
labels = Map[ToString, vars];
```

Set the variables to their corresponding values:

```
Thread[Evaluate[vars] = values]

{a, b, c}
(* Out[]= {1, 2, 3} *)
```

You can then show the grid using the variable names stored in `labels`.

```
Grid[{labels, values}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Another option is to avoid setting the variables altogether, and use them to construct rules instead.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
vars = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};
values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
rules = Thread[vars -> values]
(* Out[]= {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5, f -> 6, g -> 7} *)

{a, b, c} /. rules
(* Out[]= {1, 2, 3} *)
```

```
Grid[{vars, values}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]